# Как правильно произнести: расположЕна или располОжена?

Tags: орфоэпия

РасположЕна или РасполОжена  ?

Comment: В качестве эксперимента произнесите то, что написано. Начиная с КАК.

Answer (score 1):

Орфоэпический словарь Аванесова:располОжена и расположенА. В мужском роде:асполОжен и расположЁн.
http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/scan/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0493.gif